# API Platform GraphQL security

Tags: symfony, graphql, symfony4, api-platform.com

So I'm using API platform in my Symfony 4 project, and I've read that it supports graphQl, so I set up an access control in security.yml to allow users to access graphQl API:

```
- { path: ^/api/graphql, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

And in each entity I have access controls for itemOperations and collectinOperations. Example:

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *         }
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
```

But issue is, any user can access this entity through graphQL, because graphQL ignores the access controls for these operations.
Is there a way to force graphQL to follow these rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemOperations` and `collectionOperations` are not related to GraphQL but only to REST.

You need to add access controls in GraphQL operations or, if you want to target REST *and* GraphQL (without distinguishing operations though), you can add it as an `attribute`.

Also, `access_control` is deprecated. You should use `security` instead.

You can also read this documentation: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#security

Comment: Is there any way to apply security controls on certain graphql operations? For example if i want to allow search as specific ID but not allow retrieving all records.